# Adding a Value to an Array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, constructor

I have a method which needs to add the provided bank account to an array which I have created:

```
public boolean addAccount (BankAccount newAccount[]) {
        if (numAccounts == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
            for(int counter=0; counter<newAccount.length; counter++)
                newAccount[counter] += accounts;
        }
    }
```

it is tested by this method:

```
public static boolean test5() {
    System.out.println("Test5: add an account to a customer.");
    BankAccount b = new BankAccount();
    Customer c1 = new Customer("Alice", "Smith");
    customerCounter ++;
    if (!c1.addAccount(b))
        return false;

    return c1.toString().equals("Alice Smith, " + c1.getCustomerID() + "\n" + b.toString() + "\n");
}
```

However I am getting an error which eclipse does not have a solution for in this line:

`newAccount[counter] += accounts;`

Comment: The compiler should give you some warning about unreachable code (`for` after `return`)

Comment: Didn't get an error of unreachable code. I've modified it to this.newAccount[counter]+=accounts; and now I get an error saying newAccount is not a field.

Comment: Start with Java tutorials, like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/TOC.html

Comment: Oleg Estekhin, what if the array was initialized to `null`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to improve the code quality. Re-design your function and data structure.

- In the addAccount function, where did you derive/manipulate 'numAccounts'?
- In method parameter, use List instead of array 'BankAccount newAccount[]'. Use like (List accounts). Then you can use accounts.add() method.
- what is the definition of 'accounts'?
- Do you really need to return anything from this method?
- after return statement, no code will be executed. move 'return' statement as the last statement.

Paste the full code to get idea about overall structure.

Answer (score 0):

If u just want to see how a new value can be added to an array then here it is...

```
    int myArray[]={10,20,30};
    int newNumber=200;   //new value to be added

    /*Size of an array doesn't change once it is initialized,so a new Array must be 
      created (with new Size )to add new values.*/
    int newArray[]=new int[myArray.length+1];

    //The newArray will have {0,0,0,0};

    // Now copy all the data from previous array to new array.
    for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
        newArray[i]=myArray[i];

   //Now the content of newArray is {10,20,30,0}

    newArray[newArray.length-1]=newNumber;

    //Now the final content of newArray is {10,20,30,200}.
```

Now,Having said that, I agree with @Turing85 and @Shafiul.With your above code,you will eventually get **unreachable code**  and also **Type Incompatible** errors and yes,kindly redesign your code.

Comment: if I want to initialize my array to null entries, can I just put null for int myArray[]=null?

Comment: if u do that,then your array will point to nothing.But if you want null entries,then you have to change the datatype of your array to string.